# Should I periodically restart my lemon grass?

Tags: grass, herbs, propagation

This year my lemon grass is not doing so well. I blame the weather. It's been quite variable last summer and there have been relatively big temperature swings.

We're in autumn now. Next summer should I grab a few choice stalks to propagate and start over?

Answer (score 2):

You can always split crown crops when they get bigger, I wouldn't strip them down to one corm each, but I'd split the crown and give them some new homes with nice fresh compost mixed in.

Comment: This is what I did a few years back which lead to 3 small separate pots of lemon grass. Last year I combined all the pots into a single large pot. They were doing well, until the end of this year.